# CSS element won't move

Tags: html, css, testing

I am trying to make a platformer. I am currently on collision detection. I have set up a test platform. However, even when I try to set it up in a good testing place, it won't move. I have tried setting my object's `position` attribute to `position: absolute;`, but it doesn't change. Here's my HTML:

```
<img src="test.png" alt="move" id="p1" class="platforms">
```

CSS:

```
#p1 {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 190;
    bottom: 300;
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using Javascript for the movement of the element? Can you show us this?

Comment: I'm just setting it up right now, sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: I called it JS move because I was not thinking and didn't just use CSS instead of changing the attribute on the page load.

Comment: I noticed you used values without a unit for left and bottom. Try `left: 190px;` and `bottom: 300px;`

Comment: @ArturNoetzel — That was pointed out half an hour previously when the question was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin: You're right, I noticed this too late. I guess the comment does not hurt anybody though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful to see what this `img` element is wrapped in.

Usually when an element with `absolute` positioning isn't moving as expected, it helps to check if the parent element has `relative` positioning.

Comment: It isn't wrapped in anything.